# Where Can I find US Roads? “OverWeight Trucking Business”

Tags: data, united-states

I tried OSM, Google Maps, TIGER Database... But there's nothing like how the permits of the OverWeight Trucks roads are issued.

Any idea about this?

Comment: what exactly is overweght truck permits? can you provide an example and how are you expecting the data to be served?

Comment: An example, the texas state: https://txpros.txdmv.gov

Comment: http://www.txdmv.gov/motor-carriers/oversize-overweight-permits/txpros-info-and-tutorials
And a youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DMnvvsTwB8

Comment: Is it done on a state-by-state basis, with a different system for each state? Are you hoping someone has unified all the states into a single API? The Texas one talks about going on training courses so I fear it is more complex than you think.

Comment: Yeah! each state has its own... 
That'd be great if there's a single API or at least a Single Database...